# Encapsulating common Try-Catch code. Is this a known pattern? Is it good or bad?

Tags: c#, error-handling, extension-methods

In an effort to reduce code duplication, I often use and have used this style to capture handling of exceptions on a boundary of an application:
Given the following extension methods:

```
public static class FuncExtenstion
{
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public static Action<A> AsAction<A, T>(this Func<A, T> f)
    {
        return (a) => f(a);
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public static Func<bool> AsFunc(this Action a)
    {
        return () => { a(); return true; };
    }
}

public static class IlogExtensions
{
    public static TResult TryCatchLogThrow<TResult>(this ILog logger, Func<TResult> f)
    {
        try
        {
            return f();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
            throw;
        }
    }

    public static void TryCatchLogThrow(this ILog logger, Action f)
    {
        logger.TryCatchLogThrow(f.AsFunc());
    }

    public static TResult TryCatchLog<TResult>(this ILog logger, Func<TResult> f)
    {
        try
        {
            return f();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex.Message, ex);
            return default(TResult);
        }
    }

    public static void TryCatchLog(this ILog logger, Action f)
    {
        logger.TryCatchLog(f.AsFunc());
    }
}
```

In the code I will use these (e.g. in a Windows/WCF/Web Service) to either silently catch the error and let the code continue to run (used in a polling service) or to at least log the error locally on the server and then rethrow the full exception again. 
I have used several other variations where the exception gets wrapped in more 'user friendly' exceptions or in WCF `FaultExceptions`

So typically this code is used as follows:

```
    Response ISomeService.SomeOperation(Request request)
    {
        return _logger.TryCatchLogThrow(() => _domainImplementation.SomeOperation(request));
    }

    OtherResponse ISomeService.OtherOperation(OtherRequest request)
    {
        return _logger.TryCatchLogThrow(() => _domainImplementation.OtherOperation(request));
    }
```

I have not seen this style of code anywhere else. So I was wondering if there is an other pattern I should be using, or if this is ok to use.

Comment: I don't know about this kind of pattern, but wouldn't it be more proper to extend the logger class and silence the exceptions you don't need?

Comment: @Laurent I am essentially extending the logger class (the ILog interface here is from the [http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/](Common.Logging) framework). Yet please focus on the use of the `TryCatchxxx` method; encapsulating common TryCatch logic.

Comment: I like this pattern; this is pretty slick.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like the [Execute Around](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ExecuteAroundMethod) pattern in its static syntax. A thunk is passed around, and then invoked at the appropriate moment.

The intent is however a bit different. In true execute around, the is something done before and something done after a certain action/function/block. Catching exceptions "feels" a bit different.

Answer (score 2):

The general advice for years has been ["Do not catch general exception types"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182137%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). This has been debated in many places, including [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938/is-it-really-that-bad-to-catch-a-general-exception). Basically, the advice only holds true if you don't rethrow the exception. Since you are, at least in one instance, it's not a big deal. The `TryCatchLog` is a little more dangerous, since you're not rethrowing, but merely logging. That opens the potential for the application to be in a bad state.

Comment: While this is true most of the time -- there are always certain places where catching general exceptions is absolutely required -- as the poster indicates, those methods are being used in the top level of a polling service, which I think is a perfect place for them.

Answer (score 1):

**Aspect-Oriented Programming**

Rather than wrapping methods (which still is kind of boiler-plate code, which you wanted to get rid of in the first place), use [AOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). AOP allows you to write and configure the wrapper functionality at a single place. Known frameworks for AOP are:

- [ContextBoundObject](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.contextboundobject?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Autofac](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html)
- [And many others..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633710/what-is-the-best-implementation-for-aop-in-net)

---

**Exception hiding**

The problem with code like this..

> ```
> try
> {
>     return f();
> }
> catch (Exception ex)
> {
>     logger.Error(ex.Message, ex); // <- could throw error that hides 'ex'
>     throw;
> }
> ```

..is that it can hide the original exception `ex`. There are some situations that could invoke this unwanted behavior, for instance:

- if ex is `OutOfMemoryException`, chances are `logger.Error` would throw its own instance of `OutOfMemoryException`, hiding the original error and stack trace.
- if `logger` throws an error logging the original error (however, most logger frameworks tend to have fallback after fallback to try to mitigate an error propagating up)

At least, make the code a bit more robust. This is one way. Another is to build an `AggregateException` containing both errors, but this introduces new potential issues (what if we fail building the error..) that need to be addressed.

```
try
{
    return f();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    try
    {
        logger.Error(ex.Message, ex); // <- you will not hide my error!
    }
    catch
    { 
        // we did what we could..
    }
    throw;
}
```